# Rust tokio cancellable future

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I currently have a load tester that uses `tokio::spawn()` to start thousands of clients that in a loop do something like this:

```
let next = stream.message().await
...
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
let next = if_cancelled(cancel_fut, stream.message()).await
...
```

The idea here would be that the application would have a global cancellation future, which signal handlers in main could complete. This would cause all sockets to disconnect immediately.

How would one accomplish this? Is there some standard pattern for accomplishing this?

Comment: What would `next` contain if cancelled?

Comment: I would assume that any Err(Foo) would be fine.

Comment: You can use a [`watch`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/index.html) channel with a `select!`.

Comment: I would recommend a [`CancellationToken`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/sync/struct.CancellationToken.html) but yeah the `if_cancelled` implementation would need a `select!` over both futures.

Comment: Note that you if you have handles to the tasks you may not need this: you can just [`abort()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort) them.

Comment: Passing around a single CancellationToken and doing a select! at relevant points did the trick.